# Unable to access the karate-config.js inside my handler.feature file

Tags: java, testing, karate, web-api-testing

I was trying to access the karate-config.js file inside the features file. Created a file name karate-config.js

```
function fn(){
var config = {
name:"test",
baseUrl: "http://example.com"
}
return config;
}
```

but unable to access the baseUrl inside the handler.feature file.
[image: handler.feature]

I got an error response of undefined
[image: Error Response I get]

I have also gone through the folder structure.
[image: Folder Structure]

I have gone through the documentation of karatelabs and had followed the same steps but unable to make it work.

Comment: your post does not follow stack overflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - also I don't think anyone can help you unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue